# Creating good looking hand-drawn logos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, drawing-tablet

I like to make little logos as a hobby, and I wanted to make a patriotic looking one with and eagle. Not knowing exactly how to create it with a mouse, I got my tablet out and drew this nice looking logo:

[image: Hand-drawn logo]

I does look cool, but it's more of a concept drawing than anything. I want to know how I can make this look more finished. Anyone have some techniques I can use?

Comment: Essentially..... Practice.

Comment: Well that doesn't help much.

Comment: I disagree. Practicing is the most helpful thing you can do.

Comment: You're essentially asking "how do I get better at drawing?" and the answer to that is exactly as Scott states, practice. And then practice some more.

Comment: I tend to disagree with both Scott and DAO1. One can be really good with pencil and paper, and create the most beautiful handcrafted logo after years of practicing. That still doesn't help in making a digital version that has a more 'finished' look and can be used on the web, in print, etc.
On a sidenote: five people putting a question on hold? Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, compliments with the logo. Looks cool.

Second, on to business: Illustrator has a built-in tracing tool you could use.
Just paste the image in and use

```
Object > Live Trace > Tracing Options...
```

Tutorial can be found [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html), or by googling around.

Play around with the settings until you're satisfied with the result. Protip: turn on 'preview' and then set it to 'tracing with outline' to see what you'll be getting. 
Once you clicked 'make', don't forget to 'expand' it to create the paths.
Then you can just adjust the paths like you would normally do.

If live tracing isn't working for you, you can always trace it by hand with the pen tool (as stated by Amanda). This is slower and harder, but gives you more control.

Another option would be to use Photoshop's brushes to essentially redraw the image with your mouse/tablet. But the downside would be that you don't have vectors, so scaling isn't going to be as easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the image into Illustrator, then trace it using the tools, starting with the pen tool. This tutorial was enough for me to successfully trace a sketch I was working on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PDgoisoCwo